# Trying to pass a foreach loop but it I am getting an invalid argument. Why is that?

Tags: php, foreach

I tried the if(is_array()) and I get the h1 heading appear again instead of an error, but that does not help me much. I tried this code on phpcodechecker and it says nothing is wrong with it, but on my browser I keep getting an invalid argument for the foreach(). I tried changing $json to $jsondata, still nothing. Could someone assist me in figuring out why or how is this foreach an invalid argument?

```
<?php
        $jsondata = file_get_contents("movies.json");
        $json = json_decode($jsondata, true);
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <style>
                h1 {text-align: center;}
                h4 {margin:0; padding:5px; background:#f4f4f4;}
                li{list-style:none; padding-left:5px;}
                #container {width: 600px;}
            </style>

            <title>PHP Loops: My Movies</title>

        </head>

        <body>
            <div id="container">
                <h1>My Favorite Movies</h1>
                <ul>
    <?php

    foreach($json['movies.json'] as $key => $value) {
            echo '<h4>'.$value['title'].'</h4>';
            echo '<li>Year: '.$value['year'].'</li>';
            echo '<li>Genre: '.$value['genre'].'</li>';
            echo '<li>Director: '.$value['director'].'</li>';
        }



    ?>
                </ul>
            </div>


        </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: It's because whatever is in `$json['movies.json']` is not [traversable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php) by `foreach`. Try dumping out those contents (instead of `foreach`). You are likely expecting an array at that index and are not getting one

Comment: I tried var_dump and I got this: string(879) " "movies": [ { "title": "Saving Private Ryan", "year": "1998", "genre": "Action", "director": "Steven Spielberg" }, { "title": "Carnage", "year": "2011", "genre": "Comedy, Drama", "director": "Roman Polanski" }, { "title": "The Guard", "year": "2011", "genre": "Comedy, Crime, Thriller", "director": "John Michael McDonagh" }, { "title": "Calvary", "year": "2014", "genre": "Drama", "director": "John Michael McDonagh" }, { "title": "Chef", "year": "2014", "genre": "Adventure, Comedy, Drama", "director": "Jon Favreau" } ]; " NULL , what now?

Comment: Looks like you need `$json['movies']` instead of `$json['movies.json']`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Update from the comments:

The data in the .json file is bad and is causing errors when you are decoding it.

It should look like this: http://pastebin.com/LePFwVzW. You should be traversing `$json['movies']`.

Comment: Option 1 did not work for me, here is the contents of the movies.json file: http://pastebin.com/PCmTr0bw

Comment: Yeah, your file is bad and is causing errors when decoding. It should look like this: http://pastebin.com/LePFwVzW. You should be traversing $json['movies'].

Comment: @Angel: Your comment is the right answer, update your previous answer.

Comment: Angel, you solved it I had the missing curly braces in the json file, missed that important detail. Thank you. Please post your comment as the answer so I can check it.

Comment: It is done, I removed the first part of the answer (option 1).